# str_replace('\"','',$str) not working on server why?

Tags: php, string, replace

I am using

```
str_replace('\"','',$str);
```

to replace the `'\"'` from php script. Its correctly working on `localhost`.

When uploading its not working on server. Why ?

The script is like,  $str=http://www.keralatourism.org/beta-images/Newsletter.jpg\"">
To remove the  \" using
echo str_replace('\"','',$str);

Its working on local host but not in live server

Comment: str_replace (http://php.net/manual/it/function.str-replace.php) is not making changes in-place, but rather returns a new string.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Please explain or even better show code in which context you are using the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely clear but if you want to remove backslashes just user `stripslashes`

```
 $str= 'http://www.keralatourism.org/beta-images/Newsletter.jpg\""';
 echo stripslashes($str);
```

If you are trying to remove the double quotes:

```
$str= 'http://www.keralatourism.org/beta-images/Newsletter.jpg\""';
echo str_replace ('"', '', $str);
```

Wrap the double quotes inside single quotes.

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

the double quote does not need to be escaped unless it's wrapped in double quotes.
`str_replace('"','',$str);`
or
`str_replace("\"",'',$str);`

if you want to find the back slash as well I believe you would have to escape it with another back slash.

`str_replace('\\"','',$str);`
or
`str_replace("\\"",'',$str);`

if you want to find `&quot;` instead of `"` then you need to change the `"`" to `&quot;` PHP sees these as different.

Comment: OP is trying to remove the string `\"`

Comment: wait.. is it `\"` or `\&quot;`? they both appear the same in the browser but to PHP they are very different..